# Check for badsectors

Tags: ssd, disk-check

What are the commands to check for bad sectors in all partitions of SSD that is running Ubuntu?If I get the awnser,probably I'll ask about how to fix this in the next post... Being carefully to don't posting a duplicated question.

Answer (score 2):

```
lsblk
```

To determine the DEVICE name of SSD, e.g. sda, sdb, sdc, etc.

```
smartctl -a /dev/DEVICE
```

Where DEVICE is the name from the first command.  This will produce all the statistics for your SSD.

Typically, Reallocated_Sector_Ct is associated with the count of sectors that have been flagged as bad.

If necessary, smartmontools is the package to install for the smartctl utility.

Comment: And about interpreting the SMART values, [see here](https://ma.juii.net/blog/interpret-smart-attributes) (wrote that some years back for HDD drives). For `Reallocated_Sector_Ct`, 100 is best, meaning "100%".

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for `badblocks`, but I always check SMART data first (*ie. ask the drive how healthy it is using its logs*) using `smartctl` or `gnome-disks` before I use it.

`man badblocks` provide the following (or you can read it online with http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/badblocks.8.html)

> badblocks is used to search for bad blocks on a device (usually a disk
>   partition).  device is the special file corresponding to the device
>   (e.g /dev/hdc1).  last-block is  the  last block  to  be  checked;  if
>   it is not specified, the last block on the device is used as a
>   default.  first-block is an optional parameter specifying the starting
>   block  number  for the  test,  which  allows  the  testing  to start
>   in the middle of the disk.  If it is not specified the first block on
>   the disk is used as a default.